# Clicking on the button as soon as i Enter 6 Digit number in the Box

Tags: selenium, automation

I am working in selenium and in one of the case i need to click on the button as soon as i enter a six digit number in the text field. Anybody having any suggestions how to do that

I am new to selenium so if anybody having any idea please share

Answer (score 0):

Create a method where you pass the text of 6 digit number and then click a button. For example:

```
    public void passNumber(String digit) {
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".textfield")).sendKeys(digit);
    driver.findElement(By.id("accept-button")).click();
}
```

use a driver method called FindElement to locate the element in the DOM, and then call sendKeys() on it or other methods like click().
You can learn more about locators from [here](https://testautomationu.applitools.com/web-element-locator-strategies/)

Comment: actually those digits are random and changes every time more like a otp , So i need to enter those six digit otp and then what i want is that the button should be clicked as soon as i enter the six digit otp

Comment: Use a single if statement inside the method.